# cache on another jvm

Tags: hibernate, hazelcast

We have a hibernate 2nd level cache working on the same jvm for hibernate. Was wondering if someone has a hazelcast.xml file which hibernate can use to connect to it as a 2nd level cache on a different jvm instance.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that using hazelcast client.

Have a look at following for xml config. details.
http://www.hazelcast.com/docs/1.9.4/manual/multi_html/ch12.html